# How to handel kendo grid scrollbar in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, scrollbar

I am not able to find the xpath or handel the scroll bar in kendo grid using selenium webdriver.
I want to scroll right on the horizontal bar. Can anyone please help me out?[Please check the highlighted scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nhMZ.png)

checked with java script code but not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through Selenium click on some element which is on the right side of the page, so it will automatically scroll.

Comment: One question, why does clicking on some element which is on the right side of the page results in automatic scroll?